# Quarkus: Copy resources when running quarkus:dev goal

Tags: maven, quarkus

I have a webapp that I need to copy the Java files into my output Quarkus application because I display the code snippets as help in the web pages.  Currently the only way I could figure it out is by always calling `compile` when running `mvn compile quarkus:dev` goal.  However this is not standard as most Quakrus apps just work with `mvn quarkus:dev` out of the box!

My question is how to I attach to the Quarkus lifecycle of plugins?

My current copy-resources only works in `compile` phase which does not seem to run in `quarkus:dev` mode.

**Copy Resources Plugin:**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-java-files</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <propertiesEncoding>UTF-8</propertiesEncoding>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Current Quarkus Plugin:**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
                <goal>generate-code</goal>
                <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any help our guidance would be appreciated!

I have tried many different `<phase>` attributes for my plugin but none of them seem to execute in the Quarkus lifecycle and I could not find any documentation on Quakrus site how to do so?

Comment: Thing is that we call a plugin goal directly (`quarkus:dev`), hence no mave lifecycles are actually executed. The only way I can think of is to get into the `quarkus:dev`execution. This would mean to write a quarkus extension. I am, however, not entirely sure if it is possible to do what you want within a quarkus extension.

Comment: This can be supported. Could you please create a github issue, @Melloware?

Comment: @AlexeyLoubyansky done!  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported as an enhancement to Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30166

A good workaround suggested by user "famod" is to create a profile and then just call `mvn -Pqdev` with the following profile.

```xml
<profile>
   <id>qdev</id>
   <build>
      <defaultGoal>compile quarkus:dev</defaultGoal>
   </build>
</profile>
```

**Edit 06/01/2023:**  Quarkus 3.2.0.Final will include this finally so you can just do normal compile phase etc.  Fixed with this PR: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/33617